# ¿Cuál es la traducción literal de ‘me voy a cargar’?

Tags: traducción

Yo sé que esta expresión se usa cuando alguien necesita usar el baño, pero no entiendo porque.

Es la traducción literal ‘I’m going to carry/charge/load’?

Comment: Estás seguro de que es "cargar" y no ["cagar"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6cdswLQ), que no es sino un coloquialismo para [defecar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C1B06zc)? A literal translation of "me voy a _cagar_" would be "I'm going to _shit_".

Comment: Sometimes its used like "echar a perder/estropear/break"

Comment: Like "Me voy a cargar la ventana"/Im going to break the window

Answer (score 4):

The literal translation of "me voy a cargar" is what you suspected where **cargar** means **load, charge or carry** but that is not the intended meaning.

Announcing you are going to the bathroom is not the nicest thing and announcing that your are going there to do number 2 is even less nice. It is too much information.

So people that still want to do the no very nice announcement,  mask a little bit the sentence and use "me voy a ca**r**gar" but the real sentence would be "me voy a [cagar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6cdswLQ)" meaning "I'm going to the bathroom to poop"

I do not advice you to use either sentence. Instead you could use more "educated" sentences like

- > Necesito usar el baño
- > Voy al baño  / Voy a ir al baño.

These sentences give "enough" information.

Answer (score 0):

Hola bueno yo nativo en el idioma español esta expresion: **‘me voy a cargar’?**
la podria usar para diferentes cosas por ejemplo podria siginifcar que voy a obtener energia para hacer alguna tarea, por ejemplo se podria decir  algo asi:

hello well I am native in the language spanish this expression **‘me voy a cargar’?** I could use in different something for example could meaning that I will going to get power for do some homework, for example I could use some this way:

**Me voy a cargar de energia para hacer mi tarea**

**I will going to get power for do my homework**

or

**me voy a cargar a ese hombre**

**I will kill that man**